# Is it okay to pass strings from user memory to printk?

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel, kernel

I am new to kernel programming, and confused about how you should handle data in user memory. If I confirm that the return value of `strlen_user(user_str)` does not equal zero, is it okay to pass user_str to `printk` , or should I always copy `user_str` to kernel memory instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always copy the userspace string when accessing it from kernel.

Suppose that userspace application have several threads. One allocates string on heap and passes it to your kernel module. The other thread simultaneously frees the allocated string.

Then the following situation can happen:

- first userspace thread passes the string to kernel
- kernel validates string to be okay with `strlen_user(user_str)`
- second userspace thread frees string memory
- kernel starts working with said string

That may lead to different unwanted consequences including kernel panic.

So, use `strncpy_from_user()` function for copying string from userspace and only work with copy afterwards.

Comment: Also, **not** copying the string could result in a [TOCTOU race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use), depending on what the string is used for.  For example, if the string is used to identify a file to open and the kernel is doing some sort of custom access checking and then using the string from user-space to open the file, the user-space program can modify the contents in between the checking and the opening.  For example, after the kernel code does its custom checking for opening `/tmp/my_work_file`, the user-space process replaces it with `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: (cont)  You did fundamentally cover that, but I wanted to emphasize the potential consequences.